# Pipeline jenkins build microservice referencing a library in Jfrog artefactory

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, devops, pipeline, jfrog-cli

Good morning, I have the following scenario I have a pipeline in jenkins where I run the build of a microservice (mvn clean package) in the pom of the micro there is a dependency ej:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

This library is in jfrog artefactory but when the pipeline makes the build of the micro in the console says that it does not find the library and the build fails, is there any way to compile the micro with this library.